# My messages disappear I get a new message or send messages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've been facing this problem.

My code now disappears when get a new message. I want to make messages pile up, but I have tried many ways, but I have not solved them. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this.

When I enter a message room, I get 25 messages from firebase server.
If there are more than 25 messages, last message disappears.
Disappear message. I don't want to like this ....
[image]
[image]

I want to like this.

**here is my disappear code**

```
const messageLimit = 25;
  const [messagesSnapshot] = useCollection(
    db
      .collection('chats')
      .doc(id)
      ?.collection('messages')
      .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
      .limit(messageLimit),
  );
    if (messagesSnapshot) {
      const snap = messagesSnapshot.docs;
      const startPost = messagesSnapshot.docs[messagesSnapshot.docs.length - 1];
      setStartAt(startPost);
      const messages = snap.map(message => ({
        id: message.id,
        user: message.data().user,
        messageInfo: {
          ...message.data(),
          timestamp: message.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
        },
      }));
      setMessagesList(messages);
    }
  const getMoreMessages = async () => {
    if (!lastPost) {
      setIsGetMessagesLoading(true);
      const query = await db
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .startAfter(startAt)
        .limit(messageLimit)
        .get();
      const messages = query.docs.map(message => ({
        id: message.id,
        user: message.data().user,
        messageInfo: {
          ...message.data(),
          timestamp: message.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
        },
      }));
      setStartAt(query.docs[query.docs.length - 1]);
      setMessagesList([...messagesList, ...messages]);
      setIsGetMessagesLoading(false);
      messages.length === 0 ? setLastPost(true) : setLastPost(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    showMessages();
  }, [messagesSnapshot]);
```

Comment: Looks like you have set the message limit as 25 . So there can be only 25 messages at a time . If you get 10 new messages then your first 10 messages will be lost due to the limit .

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I don't know how to make it pile up after receiving only 25 messages at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shyam commented, you've limited the query to 25 messages, so when a new message is added, the oldest message falls out of the query.

One thing you could do is [detect the changes between the updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), and never remove the "outdated" documents.

The example from the documentation:

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

So you'd only handled `added` (which is initially every document) and possibly `modified`, but ignore `removed`.